# inserting many to many relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I want to insert many to many relations that will always be sorted by the table key.

**I'm using LINQ code:**

```
var Sorted_SXBModel = SXBModel.OrderBy(o=>o.studentName);
dbModel.Student_X_book = Sorted_SXBModel;
db.Entry(dbModel).State = EntityState.Modified; //here sorted is ok
db.SaveChanges();
```

**My student table:**

```
studID/studentName

1/jack

2/bob

5/alisha
```

When I trace my code my record is: (I want to save my record like this)

```
BookID/studentID

17/5

17/2

17/1
```

**But in sqlserver database it is:**

```
BookID/studentID

17/1

17/2

17/5
```

I do not know if my question is clear or not?

Comment: Could you please share your code a little bit elaborately?

Comment: Sorting is for presentation purposes, you do not (well, should not) care in which order your records get saved in the database. When you retrieve them, then you sort you records in whatever order is necessary.

Comment: My main code is some complicate.for example I want get first student who get this book(17). I do not want to change my database for this problem. I have a multi select in view that’s  data source is student table . And choose some student whose get a book. And first student in this multiselect is first one. But when I submit my update or add function in controller and saving my data , in database and my middle table this student ordered by id. I can not speak English well . Sorry –